# Something goes wrong with positioning in jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, positioning

Take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BramVanroy/tKL8E/

When you hover "contact" and then to its sub item "adverteren", the tooltip is displayed above the item instead of next to it. When you then go back with your mouse to "contact" and again go back to "adverteren", the tooltip displays just fine. How can this be?

Relevant code:

```
var condition = offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width()),
  properties = {},
  cssProp = {};

if (condition) {
  properties = {
    "left": (offL - tooltip.width() - 30)
  };
} else {
  properties = {
    "left": (offL + $this.width() + 25)
  };
}
$.extend(properties, {
  "top": ($this.offset().top + (posT / 2) - (tooltip.height() / 2))
});

tooltip.stop(true).text(title).animate(properties, 300).fadeTo(200, 1);
```

Comment: seeing different problem.. hover first child, then second, return to first and tooltip animation path crosses under mouse causing mouseout to trigger

Comment: yep, this is also an issue, to avoid this: boolean animation blocker is needed, which is released on title animation complete.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is because you calculate the left position based on tooltip width **before** setting the new text into it, or before browser engine re-calculate the element size.

let me check once again to find the solution or work-around.

**UPDATE:**
change your code fragment like this

```
tooltip.stop(true).text(title); // set the new text here

var condition = offL > ((wW / 2) - $this.width()),
  properties = {},
  cssProp = {};

if (condition) {
  properties = {
    "left": (offL - tooltip.width() - 30)
  };
} else {
  properties = {
    "left": (offL + $this.width() + 25)
  };
}
$.extend(properties, {
  "top": ($this.offset().top + (posT / 2) - (tooltip.height() / 2))
});

//and not here as you use width property to calculate the element position which is being changed when you change element text
tooltip.animate(properties, 300).fadeTo(200, 1);
```

check this out http://jsfiddle.net/tKL8E/42/